# Is it ok to sod or mulch over a leach field?

Tags: landscaping, septic

So we have nine people living in our house. Several teenagers means lots of showers and laundry. We have a pretty persistent wet spot at the end of our leach field but the system has been inspected and I’m told it’s fine. I’m thinking the wet spot is just due to our family size and water usage. So I’m wondering if I could plant some ornamental grass in the wet area and mulch over the top of it. I was hoping the grass would help take up the excess moisture. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a specific plant suggestion, but you want something with relatively shallow roots; that's tolerant of a wet location; and the more foliage up top (within those constraints) the better (more foliage = more transpiration (moving water from soil to air.)

Answer (score 2):

Roots are your worst enemy in this instance.  Your best bet is consulting a reputable landscaper to ask about suitable plantings for the location and desired results. A guess or recommendation from a well meaning friend or neighbor can have disastrous and expensive results down the road when plants with long growing roots clog your drainfield.